# Abend u4038 Error when moving a value from 1 variable to another variable with different picture clause

Tags: cobol

Im trying to write a program using cobol, when i try to run the program it always display the Abend s0000 u4038, well i know whats the problem , but i dont know how to fix it

So i have a variable

```
01 Ws-data.
   05 ws-branch-no   pic 9(04).

01 Ws-data2.     
   05 branch-no      pic 9(07) comp-3.


Procedure division.

Move branch-no to ws-branch-no.
Display ws-branch-no.

stop run.
```

okay like that , so the value in branch-no is '0000021' , when i try to move to ws-branch-no it got abend u4038

> The contents of data item WS-BRANCH-NO at the time of reference by statement number 1 on line 11742
> failed the NUMERIC class test or contained a value larger than the PICTURE clause as detected by the
> NUMCHECK compiler option.

i think that because the value in branch-no is 0000021 and the picture clause i set in ws-branch-no is only pic 9(04). but the point is i want the ws-branch-no value become 0021 when it moved to the ws-branch-no.

can anyone help? Thankyou

Comment: "so the value in branch-no is '0000021'" - why? Nowhere in your posted code is `branch-no` set to anything at all.

Comment: @piet.t ah sry its not the complete code , because i connect it to IMS database when i check the first value of the branch no (when i display it) is 0000021 thats why i give the example of 0000021

Comment: But that would be the interesting part: how does the value get there and how do you check it. Since it obviously isn't numeric...

Comment: @piet.t well from the copy book is already set that the branch-no is pic9(07) comp-3, then i call CBLTDLI using GU to reach the PCB , the segment and set the SSA , after that i just Display the Branch-no , and it appears .. 0000021 when i check it in spool

Comment: As a means of debugging you could try to `display Ws-data2` and view the output in hex-mode. This could show you the reason for the abend - I suspect an invalid sign-nibble.

Comment: ah sry , because of the not completed code i feel like a dumb question maker, i already found the problem , its because when i use the Get Unique then Get Next, i forgot to stop if the data reach end of data, thats why the last data that the program get is a null , and thats why it  display error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> well i know whats the problem , but i dont know how to fix it
> i think that because the value in branch-no is 0000021 and the picture clause i set in ws-branch-no is only pic 9(04).

No, this isn't the problem (at lest I'm very sure that the system you use is not that broken).
The NUMCHECK option will only be triggered if:

- the original data is not numeric (its is packed so maybe contains unpacked data?)
- the original data is too big (like 0010021)

I suggest to add a simple check:

```
  IF branch-no NOT NUMERIC
     DISPLAY 'SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN: ' branch-no ' - ' ws-data2
  END-IF.
  IF branch-no > 9999
     DISPLAY 'TOO BIG :            ' branch-no ' - ' ws-data2
  END-IF
  MOVE branch-no TO ws-branch-no
  DISPLAY ws-branch-no.
```